# Repeat scrollView animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation, uiscrollview

I've set up a animation, for my paging scrollview. Now I want to ask you, if someone knows how to repeat this animation, because my scrollview has a width of 960 and not 320. I tried to find something about this in the web, but at the end I didnt found something useful.
Could someone of you, help me with this?

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f animations:^{
    [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320, 0)animated:YES];


}];

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make a sequence of animations then

```
for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
  [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5f animations:^{
      scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(320 + 320*i, 0);    
  }];
}
```

If you want to make it once then set contentOffset with CGPoint you want (`CGPointMake(640, 0)`)

Of course contentOffset defines offset once and you can use it as you want.

Comment: well, I want the scrollview to scroll from the first page to the second and then to the third, and between this animation I want that the scrollview stops on each page

Comment: I think this solution will help. But you should insert a little delay in cycle. Then you will see scroll from the first page to the third with stops defined by yours dalays.

Comment: I found the solution posted on another awnser but thanks at all :D